# Do I really need to clear a local list?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2015

If I have a function and within that I have a list say of strings like this:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
```

. I do some stuff and then before returning form the function I do:

```
mylist.Clear();
```

Is clear really needed? OR gc will take care of things for me?

I am using C#,.Net4.5,Windows.

Comment: No, it's not needed, it costs time for no reason

Comment: GC will generally dispose of the object when you are done with it. No need to call  Clear() method.

Comment: If a class doesn't implement `IDisposable`, it's not your problem. Just [toss it out the window on the roadside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_America_Beautiful).

Comment: The list itself is managed by the GC, however instances *in* this list might live longer.

Comment: `Clear()` wouldn't get rid of it anyway. You would have to dispose it or set it to `null`.

Comment: @Skynet Setting a variable to `null` just before it goes out of scope is pointless.  That would only have value if the variable would remain in scope, but be unused, for quite some time.

Comment: I see downvotes even before getting real answers but anyways...the reason why I am asking is where I work I see quite a few scenarios where clear has been called on local lists which I found very weird, so thought there could be something I am missing.

Comment: @Servy Sure, i just wanted to point out that `Clear()` doesn't force an object to be garbage collected - The list will still be there, just empty. Obviously that's pointless if the variable is out of scope a few lines later.

Comment: @SofDev rory.ap and Patrick Hofmann's answers both provide exactly what you are asking in your comment. The clear() method is effective when you have one initialized instance of the list but have a requirement to reuse it for new elements later on.

Comment: @Servy -- There are some cases where you want to set a reference to null.  I've worked with some cranky COM APIs with RCWs that needed to be set to null to avoid a COM pure virtual function call error that crashed the whole application.

Comment: @Skynet setting the variable to `null` *also* does nothing to affect the collection of the object.

Comment: @rory.ap Sure, there are *lots* of reasons to set a variable to `null`, but "forcing an object to be garbage collected before the variable goes out of scope" just isn't one of them.

Comment: @Servy Shouldn't the garbage collector free the memory if the reference is `null` ? The last part of the quote (before the variable goes out of scope) was never mentioned by me. I know that it's very rare that you set an object to `null` for garbage collection purposes, usually you dispose it or it's out of scope very soon anyways.

Comment: @Skynet No, setting it to `null` *wont'* free the memory.  *If* the variable is the only remaining reference to that object it would make it *eligible* for collection.  Additionally, if the variable will stay in scope but the JITter can prove the value won't be read again it can *still* consider the reference dead, so the situations left, where the variable will actually be read again (but shouldn't access the current object) is *very* rare.  Additionally, the question *does* specify "right before returning from a function", so we know it's going out of scope soon anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need to clear it.  That's only if you want to use an existing list and clear the elements so you can use it again with new elements.  Once your variable goes out of scope, it will be GC'd.

If your list consists of objects (reference type instances), then those references may stay around if you have separate variables that point to them, but of course those will be GC'd as well once they go out of scope.  It has nothing to do with the list, though.

Comment: but granted that those reference type vars are not local right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I was referring to the section in your comment: '...then those references may stay around if you have separate variables...'. did you mean if they are global variables?

Comment: No I meant any variables.  Depends on where you are holding them.  In a method, in a class as a field, etc.

Answer (score 4):

No. You should not do that.

Clearing a list [clears the backing array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,303) where the actual values are stored. It returns the memory to the OS. All that is already done (and probably more efficiently) by the garbage collector. You are just creating extra work for you and the GC.